# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite() returns false

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I have checked the below code

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                        Log.d("StatusActivity", "sdcard mounted and writable");
                    }
                    else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
                        Log.d("StatusActivity", "sdcard mounted readonly");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("StatusActivity", "sdcard state: " + state);
                    }
```

The output shows `sdcard mounted and writable`

But the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()` always returns false. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission for your app. In addition, if you're writing a file that's being used only by your app, you should store it in Context.getExternalFilesDir(), to prevent spreading your app's files throughout public storage. If you *are* writing a public file, you should store it in Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

Comment: Adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> did resolve the issue ` in manifest file did resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Check if your device has enough storage space. That could also be the problem.